# How to import a python file to another python file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two python files.

one contains all the basic functions for my automation. - **Basic.py**
another one contains all scenarios to execute - **test.py**

I have to use the functions i have written in class.py in test.py. So how can i call or import basic.py in test.py ?

I tried giving

`import basic.py` but not working !!!

any help please

the basic.py is in different path.

Comment: `class.py` is not a great name - try `somethingelse.py` then `import somethingelse` (without the .py)

Comment: if they are in the same folder, then you just do `import class` but i would advise you to change that module name, otherwise you'll class with the keyword `class`

Comment: If it isn't in the same directory you can use `import sys` then
`sys.path.append("/path/to/module/.")` to update your path to include the folder containing the module and then simply `import class`

Comment: @JamesKent, I think you mean clash ;).

Comment: @Cyphase Shhhh it's early.....

Answer (score 1):

`import basic` should work, if it is in the local directory. Otherwise you will need to provide the path to the file IE `import path.to.file.basic`

Comment: @Cyhpase from working code: `import test.service.plusframework as plus` or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: I realize I should have specified; I meant the second import. You can't do `import path/to/file/test`. _Maybe_ `import path.to.file.test`, in the right conditions.

Comment: @Cyphase , can u make it bit clear. For example my path is : Users/test/Desktop/auto Suite/basic.py . This is the script file i need to import to test.py. Then how ?

Comment: @harimadhav, as you seem to be a novice (nothing wrong with that :) ), I would recommend putting `basic.py` and `test.py` in the same directory for now; then you can just do `import basic` from inside `test.py`. Also, you might want to call it something like `test_basic.py`; there is a built-in `test` module in Python. Though admittedly it's seldom used, it's a good habit to _not_ name things the same as built-ins.

Comment: @Cyphase : Thanks for that. Can you please help me also if its in different directory. So I can learn that also

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @Duncan suggested name of package or module should not be reserved keyword i.e. class so rename it to something else

To import any package or module, it must exists in PYTHONPATH

**To add a directory to Python path**

1. You can add a directory to python path at runtime using

   import sys

   sys.path.append('absolute_path_to_dir')
2. You can permanently add dir to python path using ~/.bashrc

   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/

**There are three ways to import in python:-**

1. from  import 
   E.g.:- from klass import MyClass
2. import 
   E.g.:- import klass
3. from  import *
   import all variables from the package. (should seldom be used)

**To Elaborate:-**

1. import X imports the module X, and creates a reference to that module 
   in the current namespace. Or in other words, after you’ve run this statement, you can use X.name to refer to things defined in module X.
2. from X import * imports the module X, and creates references in the current namespace to all public objects defined by that module (that is, everything that doesn’t have a name starting with “_”). Or in other words, after you’ve run this statement, you can simply use a plain name to refer to things defined in module X. But X itself is not defined, so X.name doesn’t work. And if name was already defined, it is replaced by the new version. And if name in X is changed to point to some other object, your module won’t notice.
3. from X import a, b, c imports the module X, and creates references in the current namespace to the given objects. Or in other words, you can now use a and b and c in your program.
4. Finally, X = **import**(‘X’) works like import X, with the difference that you 1) pass the module name as a string, and 2) explicitly assign it to a variable in your current namespace.

Note:-
For this to work, package should exist in PYTHONPATH

Comment: If its from another path then ?

Comment: You need to add that path to PYTHONPATH

Comment: Note that `import class` is a syntax error. Don't give Python modules the same names as reserved words.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that

Comment: @hspandher can you tell me how ?

Comment: @harimadhav Tell you what? I couldn't understand

Comment: @hspandher : For example my path is : Users/test/Desktop/auto Suite/basic.py . This is the script file i need to import to test.py. Then how ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I guess that answers your query. Let me know in case of any issues